# Chrome dev-tools file system - how to edit a file loaded in the dev tools from javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I enabled fileSystem tab in developer tools, and I'm able to see source of current html file that is loaded in the browser.

I want to try out what happens if I edit this html while that html file is loaded, so that it mimics the hot reloading behaviour of bundling tools.

For example, lets say my html has some content inside a div, I used javascript to edit that text, so what I would do is write a javscript that listens to change event of the input field.

Once the user blurs out, I'd write to the source of the html directly, so that I dont have to reload the browser at all.

I looked at few of the API's bur most of them are letting me to open filesystem dialog, which is not what I 'm looking for